# Is it possible to record the bevel factor as a keyframe in the action editor?

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

Just starting to get my head around animations in blender.

Rather than jumping straight into a rigged model, I smooshed together two things I had seen done in videos:

1. Using the action editor to make an action
2. Modifying the Bevel Factor on a bezier curve in order to grow a vine-like structure. (In my project it's a stylised trail from a spaceship.)

But, however much I change options around and use different methods of recording keyframes and swear, I can't get any keyframes recorded in the action editor, although they record fine in the dope sheet.

Is it possible to record the bevel factor as a keyframe in the action editor and I'm just doing something wrong?  Or are there limits to what can be recorded in an action?  How can I tell what those limits are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because **bevel depth** is not an **object** property - it's **curve data** property. **Action editor** shows only one **animation block** (bordered with red line):

[image]

Outer **animation blocks** doesn't display in **action editor**

So what you can do - create a **property** in **object data** and make **driver** to manipulate **bevel depth** value in **curve data** 
through **object data**.

**Howto**:

1. In object data find tab **custom properties**  and add one:

[image]

2. Next, open **curve data** side by side and press RMB on **bevel depth**:

[image]

Chose **add driver** -> **single from target**, and (when your cursor will be as dropper) click on value created before.

3. So now you have value in **action editor**, that manipulates **bevel depth**:

   [image]

Comment: Incredible.  Thank you so much!  I even know what to look for to know what I can add to action editor.

Comment: @hainsay Don't just thank in the comments, this site works best if you upvote the answer. If it solved your problem consider making it as accepted.

Comment: I did upvote but my rep is low so it doesn't show.  Have now also accepted.