# Water like simulation through pipes without using fluid physics and baking data

Tags: fluid-simulation

Can someone please tell me how to create this fluid animation without using fluid physics properties in blender. Baking data is lengthy process.

Want to avoid that to show such kind of fluid animation.
Just want a fluid simulation.
It doesn't has to be real.
If you Can please tell me how to create such simulation. [image]

Comment: Hello :). Please add an example of similar animation. Based on this still image, curves with bevel could work well.

Comment: can you tell me how to do path aniamtion of this fluid fake effect. so the shaded tube starts flowing from keyframe 1 to last

Comment: Hello :). I can't post an answer now, but search for animating bezier curve bevel. Perhaps this could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/98632/78972

Comment: thank you very very much. it worked. i used bavel start and end with keyframe.